# Year to Date Calculation

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I applied the row based offset formula. However, this requires pivoting from the existing master data. Since approximately 25 - 30 variations are required, preparing and formulating Pivots for each variation is very challenging.

Row based Offset formula is as follows,

=SUM(OFFSET(C3:N3,,,,COUNTA(C5:N5)))

This formula works very well on a row basis, but as I said, too much variation creates a huge waste of time.

Therefore, the fastest solution is to do the work on the main data. For this, I need to work on the column instead of the row and get the total in the YTD cell that appears in the picture.

I would be very happy if you could help me with this.

[Yearly Actuals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0YSg.png)

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result and how it should be calculated

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LCeMaA9dyGq3jsP8S5UM5rwn80YMgMucqwPRnCYuiKE/edit#gid=0

Comment: As I mentioned, just applied offset formula based on row. but I need a formula that will calculate the column instead of the row. I searched for examples in the forum, but in general, all of the formulas are row based. Support will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(MMULT(1*(INDIRECT("B2:M"&COUNTA(A1:A)+1)), SEQUENCE(12)^0))
```

[image]

---

or:

```
=INDEX(TRANSPOSE(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(1*INDIRECT("B2:"&
 ADDRESS(13, MAX((1:1<>"")*(COLUMN(1:1)))))), SEQUENCE(12)^0)))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=INDEX(TRANSPOSE(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(1*INDIRECT("B2:"&
 ADDRESS(MONTH(TODAY())+1, MAX((1:1<>"")*(COLUMN(1:1)))))), SEQUENCE(MONTH(TODAY()))^0)))
```

[image]

Comment: I will work on these solutions. Thank you for the quick support.

Comment: Hi, your quick reaction was much appreciated. YTD should be dynamic according to the actual year, I am comparing the previous year in other files according to the actual year. I achieve this result in horizontal pivot table, but not vertically. In your Transpose example, it gives YTD total, do you have the possibility and suggestion to make it dynamic according to the actual data? It will meet my needs 100%. We are in the 7th month in actual data, it should give the first 7 months in YTD in previous years. I'll try to implement your examples if it's going to be too complicated.

Comment: not rly sure I understand what are you after... you want sum of each column but only up to todays month?

Comment: You figuredout what i'm after. Thank you for your support despite the difficulty I had in explaining the subject.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to use a [volatile function](https://chandoo.org/wp/handle-volatile-functions-like-they-are-dynamite/) if you have performance issues. It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do, but it looks like you're trying to get year over year YTD balances based on current year's months of data. In that case, and `index` function is probably fine. Something like this: `=Sum(C7:INDEX(C7:N7,1,$P$5))`

[See sample spreadsheet here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1etyH9wPO60XQoMauoMDCETVGDhqM8bVHDUCvdgDEWCE/edit#gid=0)

[image]

Comment: I will work on these solutions. Thank you for the quick support.

Comment: Ok. As a friendly reminder, StackOverFlow operates on a reputation basis, so if this works, I'd be most thankful if you click the accept button. Thanks. Good luck.

Comment: you are right, due to the time difference, I was able to look at the replies that have just come. Your sharing works, I got exactly what I need from our other registered friend. Your sharing will be of great support in different variations. Thank you very much for your support.

Comment: @UmutKırcan, thanks for your response. I'm glad you accepted one answer. Glad it works.